# refinery-edge gives error "no such file to load -- refinerycms-base (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, refinerycms

I'm trying to run refinery-edge on my Ubuntu 10.04 64bit. I have RVM installed, created the gemset "refinery-edge", and followed the [steps in the refinery website](http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started-with-edge-refinery), but when I try to create the refinery project I get the following error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- refinerycms-base (LoadError)
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from /home/felixmm/Desktop/Rails_Projects/refinerycms-edge/lib/refinerycms.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/felixmm/Desktop/Rails_Projects/refinerycms-edge/lib/refinerycms.rb:1:in `each'
from /home/felixmm/Desktop/Rails_Projects/refinerycms-edge/lib/refinerycms.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from /home/felixmm/Desktop/Rails_Projects/refinerycms-edge/lib/refinery.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from refinerycms-edge/bin/refinerycms:15:in `<main>'
```

Any help on this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed the guide as that was really for pre-0.9.9 and was asking for feedback via GitHub, please use the gem instead.

Currently the gem is up to date with edge.

Thanks